# Python: Extract TEXT from sqlite3 as a string

Tags: python, sqlite

First week programming in any language and need some help: Im trying to extract a TEXT value as a string from sqlite3 in Python.  Im getting a value as a list not a str:

```
system_id = raw_input ("What is your System ID: ")
```

For example the user enters 'Elmer'

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("API.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SYSTEMID (systemid TEXT)''')
conn.commit()
conn.close()

conn = sqlite3.connect("API.db")
c = conn.cursor()
system_id = c.execute('select systemid from SYSTEMID').fetchall()
conn.close()
```

So how to make the variable system_id as a string?  If I print from this I get something like [(u, Elmer)], I want system_id = Elmer

Comment: its the `fetchall()` that returns a `list` of tuples. The problem is not the variable type. Print the current `system_id` and you will see. Then depending on what you actually need, you can do something like: `system_id = system_id[0][0]` i guess..

Comment: yeah I half guessed fetchall() was wrong, but how do I express fetchElmer()

Comment: by executing a better query. somehting along the lines of `select systemid from SYSTEMID where user = "Elmer"`

Comment: Ok I dont know hat the value will be in advance, but this has worked:
system_id = str(system_id[0][0])

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [Ev. Kounis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6162307/ev-kounis), `fetchall()` by default will return a `list` of `tuple`s with length equal to the variables specified.

In your case you are getting a tuple of length 1, because you asked for a single variable.

The `u` in front of the string `'Elmer'` is also returned by default when getting strings (this just means it is a Unicode String).

There are two things you should do:

1. Get rid of `u` by changing `text_factor` of the connection to `str` like this:

   ```
   con.text_factory = str
   ```
2. Accessing first element of the tuple to only get the string `'Elmer'`:

   `fetch = c.execute('select systemid from SYSTEMID').fetchall()`
   `system_id = fetch[0][0] # First element in first tuple in list`

Comment: Thanks, I will try, my less elegant solution was system_id = str(system_id[0][0])